# Ubuntu 19.04 Desktop - Dash is crashing the desktop and log out the user

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.04, gnome-dash

I tried to upgrade to Ubuntu 19.04 through the software-update and it kinda worked well this time, except that it failed that a menu is not installed properly and issue with that and it'll start rollback to the old version.

I thought it's going to be okay and it'll rollback and nothing happened for an hour, so I restarted the system. Now I am in Ubuntu 19 and all the applications work fine but the problem is I can't access the dash menu (start menu).

Every time I try to open dash or press the window key, the desktop environment crashes and pushes me to the lock screen. I am not entirely sure what's missing here and don't know where to look up for the cause.

Let me know if you need me too look up for the logs somewhere and paste it here.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 19 with standard Ubuntu releases being *yy.mm* in format; Ubuntu Core is an exception but that uses *yy* format but hasn't come out this year.  Thus I'm wondering how you did your upgrade?  Did you use an official tested tool?  (eg. `do-release-upgrade` or something else).  If it didn't complete; I'd login to a terminal, and `sudo apt dist-upgrade` to see if it'll continue & complete).  If you didn't upgrade from 18.10; you're outside of tested & supported upgrade paths anyway.

Comment: I was upgrading from Ubuntu 18.10 using do-release-upgrade. The current version shows as 19.04. If I try `sudo apt dist-upgrade` it shows 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed message.

Comment: In your position: I would `sudo apt update` (and look at the output as it scrolls to ensure 'cosmic' [18.10] lines are gone, with 'dingo' [19.04] lines having replaced them), then `sudo apt dist-upgrade` again expecting 0 to upgrade (but just to be safe).  The next likely cause that comes to mind is if you've added other gnome extensions (18.10 or before) that aren't compatible with the newer gnome release; as if these cause a 'crash', gnome-shell will exit & you're returned to login screen.

Comment: I have gnome-tweaks and bunch of other extensions installed before, maybe I'll try to remove them and see if that helps. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just did the upgrade to 19.04 from 18.10... gnome is fucking bugged as hell. It was running perfectly stable before and now I'm here with a pile of shit which crashes every 30 mins. Fuck off ubuntu.

Comment: @Eugene That was the case for me too. After erasing and reinstalling 19 is good and stable.

Comment: I just found out I had the proposed repo active.. so I have to relativize my previous comment.. The crash bug is only present in the proposed repo. Anyone who has issues should check if only stable is active. But anyway, gnome runs worse than before, even with the version in the stable repo. Still super laggy when closing file dialogues for example.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

Started gnome-tweaks from a terminal and disabled extensions.

Looks like Ubuntu appindicators caused the problem.

Comment: It didn't solve the problem for me, I just erased and reinstalled 19. It was easier that way than trying to mess with it. It saved a lot of time. :p